# Regular Expression replace single character in a word multiple times

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
INSERT INTO testtable ('Reference', 'Date', 'Address', 'Amount', 'ChequeNo') VALUES
```

How would I return only the quotes `'`

I basically need to do a replace on all the quotes from INSERT INTO up until VALUES as its invalid SQL.

Comment: There are string replacement functions that are prefect for replacing characters. Why do you want to use regex?

Comment: I have this in a text file and thought regex, what functions?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're going for... removing the quotes? Replacing them with something else?

Comment: Sorry if i didnt explain it right. I have a text file full of SQL insert functions which are all invalid! I need to remove the single quotes between the words INSERT INTO and VALUES with nothing, basically need to remove them. I have a text editor TextWrangler which allows regex which is the only way i see to do this quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you didn't mention your development environment, I assume that you just want to fix this sql problem.

this awk line can fix that for you:

```
awk -F'VALUES' '{gsub(/\x027/,"",$1);print $1FS$2;}' yourFile
```

**test**

```
kent$  echo "NSERT INTO testtable ('Reference', 'Date', 'Address', 'Amount', 'ChequeNo') VALUES('a','b','c','d','e')"|awk -F'VALUES' '{gsub(/\x027/,"",$1);print $1FS$2;}'  

NSERT INTO testtable (Reference, Date, Address, Amount, ChequeNo) VALUES('a','b','c','d','e')
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: I had made the assumption you were using Objective-C, given the presence of the `NSRegularExpression` tag.

Split it by lines, and on each line, do this:

```
[yoursqlstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"
                                         withString:@""
                                            options:NULL
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [[yoursqlstring rangeOfString:@"VALUES"] location])]
```

Regular expressions aren't meant to do what you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove *all* the single quotes, just do this:

```
NSString *newString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""];
```